# For the Rust Rocket Framework is it possible to hook up GraphQL to elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, rust, graphql, rust-rocket

I have set up the Rust Rocket web framework and I have been able to make use of the official Elasticsearch Rust crate to set up a client and get documents from the elasticsearch index. However while looking at this example https://github.com/davidpdrsn/graphql-app-example I noticed that the GraphQL that is hooked up to Postgres here uses the .attach() method supplied by rocket. I tried to do the same with my elasticsearch client by implementing the Fairing trait on the elasticsearch client but it wasn't possible. I received the following error: error[E0117]: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types. This makes sense so I tried to wrap the type and then implement the Fairing trait on it and got a separate error: `(dyn elasticsearch::http::transport::ConnectionPool + 'static)` cannot be sent between threads safely. This also makes sense since the official elasticsearch client for RUST is async.

So my question is this: can elasticsearch, graphql and Rust Rocket be set up to work together? And if they can work together, are there any good working examples? I did a lot of googling and I searched through some repos on github and was unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot advise on GraphQL integration, but there is a [section in one article that deals exactly with calling async elasticsearch-rs methods within sync Rocket v0.4](https://matej.laitl.cz/bench-actix-rocket/#calling-async-functions-from-blocking-handlers). Linked [GitHub repository with working Rocket v0.4 microservice using Elasticsearch](https://github.com/strohel/locations-rs-rocket/tree/global-rt/src).